# How to handle URL protocol error

Tags: php, html, url, protocols

I've been writing an application that executes through an URL protocol i.e. myapp://launch.

I want my site to redirect to the software download if there was an error with opening the software (most likely because it wasn't installed)

How can I manage to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The mime type handling is handled by the browser and OS. A website cannot retrieve such info.